# Javascript html input element changes how to load into function?

Tags: javascript, html

I want user to load page, default value is 10 so it should calculate all variables for default value first, then I want user to enter his own value and click submit and the value gets updated.
Seems it needs onclick event that should call a function to recalculate the value.
I tried first without intparse and .value and no onclick event, then I figured out I need Intparse and .value to get integer. When setting default value on input id 1 it calculates three numbers correctly upon page load.
However when I put it in a function before it would calculate all three numbers correctly then page would reload for some reason and it goes back to default, This one doesn't work at all.
Can somebody explain what I did wrong?

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="frm1">
    <input type="number" id="1" name="1" value="10"><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" id="s" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <p id="t"></p>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    Function myFunction() {
        var N = parseInt(document.getElementById("1").value);
        var m = N;
        var cm = m * 100;
        var mm = m * 1000;
        document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = "" + m + " " + cm + " " + mm; }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It should be `function` not `Function`. Also your page reloads because you're using a `<form>` with a "submit" button. You don't need the `<form>` at all.

Answer (score -1):

Change the form to a div. This worked for me when I tried to run your code.